# Hokuyo_node for hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ros_hydro and I need to run the hokuyo_node
I tried to install the urge_node `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-urg-node`
And then when i launch  `rosrun urg_node urg_node`
It says : `Error: stack/package urg_node not found`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188121/hokuyo_node-for-hydro/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you check if there is urg_node in /opt/ros/hydro/share with a command `roscd urg_node`?
I guess that urg_node is not installed yet. At installing it, you might look at an error message.
If you look at error message like `E: Could not open lock file ~` and `E:Unable to lock directory ~`, you should use `sudo apt-get update`. Please pay attention to input with sudo.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2014-07-30**:
I just installed ros-hydro-urg-node without any issues.  You may need to run sudo apt-get update before installing.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-30**:
I did sudo apt-get update! Today, I tried to install `ros-hydro-urg-node` with `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-urg-node` again. I could do that. I guess that it's the problem of network environment in my case. At my apartment, I couldn't do,but at my lab I could do that.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-31**:
I'm sorry, @mjcarroll. you might be right. I might have executed apt-get update without`sudo`.